# Kmeans clustering time on scikit

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-means

How much time should it take to cluster a set of 100'000 L2 normalized 2048-dim feature vectors using k-means with 200 clusters? I have all my data in a huge numpy array, maybe there's a more appropriate data structure?

It didn't seem to do any progress in an hour. I'm also inclining to use the threshold stopping criteria, but it seems to take more than 5 minutes for just 2 iterations. Is there some sort of verbose command I can use to check in on the progress for kmeans clustering on scikit-learn? Does anyone suggest any other approach? Maybe something like dimensionality reduction, or PCA and then kmeans? (I'm just throwing random ideas out there)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you haven't tried it yet, use [`sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#mini-batch-kmeans) instead of `sklearn.cluster.KMeans`

E.g., if `X.shape = (100000, 2048)`, then write

```
from sklearn.cluster import MiniBatchKMeans
mbkm = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=200)  # Take a good look at the docstring and set options here
mbkm.fit(X)
```

`MiniBatchKMeans` finds slightly different clusters from normal `KMeans`, but has the huge advantage that it is an online algorithm which doesn't need all the data at every iteration and still gives useful results.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [faiss kmeans](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss/wiki/Faiss-building-blocks:-clustering,-PCA,-quantization). It only took me 3s:

```
>>> x = np.random.randn(100_000, 2048)
>>> kmeans = faiss.Kmeans(2048, 200, verbose=True)
>>> kmeans.train(x)

Sampling a subset of 51200 / 100000 for training
Clustering 51200 points in 2048D to 200 clusters, redo 1 times, 25 iterations
  Preprocessing in 0.21 s
  Iteration 24 (3.01 s, search 2.39 s): objective=1.03945e+08 imbalance=2.689 nsplit=0
103945064.0
```

I can't say for sure that the quality will be as good as sklearn's KMeans, but it also could be better.

It's definitely better than MiniBatchKMeans, which takes about 10s on my laptop:

```
>>> mbkm = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=200, verbose=True)
>>> mbkm.fit(x)
Init 1/3 with method k-means++
Inertia for init 1/3: 11504055.270642672
...
Converged (lack of improvement in inertia) at step 205/9765
>>> mbkm.inertia_
204194114.50047162
```

Which has a 1.96 times higher inertia.
(I'm a little confused why the inertia after training seems to be worse as after k-means++ initialization.)

Another thing I would try is to reduce the dimension of your data.
Either by using a random transformation (Johnson-Lindenstrauss) or just sampling some columns.
You shouldn't really need that high a dimensionality to do k-means with just 100'000 points.